# Why does my function only return the number 8?

Tags: c

I have this block of C code that is used to determine the arabic number of given roman numerals. The problem is, this code only gives out the number 8.

```
char * romanNumerals[13] = {"I", "IV", "V", "IX", "X", "XL", "L", "XC", "C", "CD", "D", "CM", "M"};
int arabicNumbers[13] = {1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 400, 500, 900, 1000};

char * prob2(char * roman) {
    int arabic = 0;
    int romanSize = (sizeof(roman)/sizeof(roman[0]));

    for (int i = 0; i < romanSize; i++) {
        int f_arabic = arabicNumbers[findArrayPos(romanNumerals, roman[i])];
        if (i+1 == romanSize) {
            arabic += f_arabic;
            break;
        }

        int s_arabic = arabicNumbers[findArrayPos(romanNumerals, roman[i+1])];
        if (f_arabic >= s_arabic) {
            arabic += (f_arabic);
        }
        else {
            arabic += (s_arabic-f_arabic);
        }
    }

    char * answer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(arabic)+1);
    sprintf(answer, "%i\n", arabic);
    return answer;
}

int findArrayPos(char ** arr, char find) {
    int foundAt = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<sizeof(arr);i++) {
        if (arr[i] == &find) {
            foundAt = i;
        }
    }
    return foundAt;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: `sizeof(roman)` is the size of a pointer, not the array. Use `strlen()` to get the length of a string.

Comment: You don't use `==` to compare strings, you use `strcmp()`.

Comment: Likewise, `sizeof(arabic)+1` gives you the size of one `int` + 1 byte which will be 5 bytes on most platforms.

Comment: @Barmar my function still only returns the number 8, despite changing

Comment: But `find` is not a string, it's a single character. You can't compare a string and a character.

Comment: You have other problems. You're very confused about how to work with strings and characters.

Comment: @Barmar Okay, so i used &find because I knew it was a character and tried to turn in into char *. Now it returns 720

Comment: Changing the type doesn't make it a string. A string is an array of characters ending with a null byte. But there's no null byte after each character in `find`.

Comment: `&find` is the address of the `find` variable, which won't be the same as the address of the string literal in `romanNumerals`.

Comment: @Barmar how can I compare a char * to a char then?

Comment: If you just want to compare the first character of the string, you can use `if (arr[0] == find)`

Comment: But you have 2-character strings in `romanNumerals`. You won't be able to compare them to `roman[i]`.

Comment: You could pass `&roman[i]` to the function, and then use `strncmp(romanNumerals[i], find, strlen(romanNumerals[i]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `==` to compare strings. When you do that, you're comparing addresses, and two string with the same contents can be at different addresses.

Since the substrings in `roman` don't have null terminators after them, you can't treat them as ordinary strings to use `strcmp()`. But you can use `strncmp()`, which allows you to specify how many characters to compare. You can compare a substring of `roman` starting at an index with a string in `romanNumerals` this way.

To make this work most easily, you can reorder `romanNumerals` so that the 2-character strings are before their 1-character prefixes. Otherwise, when `roman` contains `IX`, for example, you'll match `I` before you get to `IX` in the array.

You can't use `sizeof array / sizeof array[0]` to get the length of an array that was passed as a parameter to a function, because the parameter is a pointer, not an array. For a string you can use `strlen()` to get its length, but for `romanNumerals` you'll need to get the length in the caller and pass it as an explicit parameter.

```
char * romanNumerals[13] = {"IV", "IX", "I", "V", "XL", "L", "XC", "X", "CD", "D", "CM", "C", "M"};
int arabicNumbers[13] = {4, 9, 1, 5, 40, 50, 90, 10, 400, 500, 900, 100, 1000};

char * prob2(char * roman) {
    int arabic = 0;
    size_t romanSize = strlen(roman);
    size_t numeralsSize = sizeof romanNumerals / sizeof romanNumerals[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < romanSize; i++) {
        int f_arabic = arabicNumbers[findArrayPos(romanNumerals, &roman[i], numeralsSize)];
        arabic += f_arabic;
    }

    char * answer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(arabic)+1);
    sprintf(answer, "%i\n", arabic);
    return answer;
}

int findArrayPos(char ** arr, char *find, size_t len) {
    int foundAt = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<len;i++) {
        if (strncmp(arr[i], find, strlen(arr[i])) {
            foundAt = i;
        }
    }
    return foundAt;
}
```

Comment: Okay so you helped me fix up most of the issues I had with the code, the problem still remains with &roman[i], where it returns the whole string instead of just the character. I am trying to turn that one character into a char *

Comment: Why do you need to do that? The string is in `romanNumerals`.